# Strange shell (bash) behavior when started from vim

Tags: bash

**Edit: Solved. See GitHub: [amix/vimrc#204](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/issues/204#issuecomment-231083581).**

I often drop a shell out of my vim window by `:!bash` but I have two problems with it.

- I can't use UTF8 for pipes
- with QWERTZ layout, I can't use Umlaut keys like `öäü`, i.e. `ö` behaves like `ALT-_`

I think the problems are somehow related.

Is there anything I missed regarding both problems?

Comment: I've no idea where your problems come from but I wonder if using `:!bash` is actually a good thing: I think that `:!` is meant to execute a single command but not to start an interactive shell. If you really need to execute several commands in an external shell why don't you directly the external shell?

Comment: Can you  give us more details please? For example, what is your OS or distribution (including version), your bash  version and the output of `vim --version`? When you  answer, we willl take it from there.

Comment: FYI. My system works perfectly and I just want to try and reproduce your problem. I use  Ubuntu 14.04 with regular vim-gtk package with what is mostly the vimrc_example file that comes with vim.

Comment: You should use either `:shell` or `<C-z>`

Comment: This is the main selling point of neovim. I'd highly recommend giving that a shot to have a full shell without limitations (well some limitations but much less than `:shell`). `:vsplit term://zsh` is a pretty nice feature IMO. I just ran into a scripting problem around this which I could assist with (open terminal mode and insert into a `nonmodifiable` ) [some fun stuff..]

Comment: Huh, took some time to answer...  @AlexandreMartins vim 7.4, bash 4.3.42(1), Debian testing. [full output](http://pastebin.com/64uppnqH)

Comment: @romainl Will try that :)

Comment: @romainl My Umlaut issue is also there if I use `:shell`.

Comment: @statox I currently can't imagine a good situation but sometimes switching to an external shell breaks my workflow. But maybe my workflow is simply ugly ^^

Comment: @DanBradbury What are the limitations of `:shell`?

Comment: @criztovyl_needs_help Your setup looks pretty standard. Can you clean your '.vimrc' to a smaill subset that still has the problem and paste it in the answer? Also mention your keyboard layout by executing 'cat /etc/default/keyboard'. Let's see if I can reproduce your problem this way. Let me also know which key conbinations do I have to press to get one of the characters you mention.

Comment: @AlexandreMartins Huh, I'm using [amix's vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc). When removing it issue is gone, so I think it's a problem of amix's vimrc. Will open issue there :)

Comment: @criztovyl_needs_help: It's good if you found the cause of the problem. I think you might be interested in [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) it allows you to split your terminal in several panels, it could be useful to you to have a split containing Vim and another one where you'd issue your terminal commands. That really helped me improving my workflow.

Comment: Good stuff @criztovyl_needs_help . Glad you managed to figure out how to  solve your problem. If you end up figuring out the root cause as well, answer your own question and make someone else's life easier. You may even hog those lovely vi.stackexchange points for yourself. :D

Comment: Redefining `$LANG` in the vimrc is a really bad idea. You use this environment variable to set your locale, which influences all sorts of things (which character encoding to use, sorting order, interface language, etc).  I appreciate there are some edge-cases where resetting this is useful, but doing this habitually is not a good idea, and this is a great example why copying a random vimrc from GitHub is probably not a great idea... At any rate, you should probably post your answer as an answer − rather than an edit to the question − so people can see your problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem here is in the `.vimrc` I use, it overwrote my locale. So I commented that out and everything works fine again.

See the corresponding GitHub issue: [amix/vimrc#204](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/issues/204#issuecomment-231083581).

Thanks to @Carpetsmoker for pointing out an answer would be more sufficent than an edit of the question ^^